# $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n ((n^5 +5n^4)^{1/5} - (n^2 +2n)^{1/2})$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n ((n^5 +5n^4)^{1/5} - (n^2 +2n)^{1/2})$$

Please, help me to find the limit.

Comment: I tried to use L'Hopitals rule but that doesn't simplify much. Yes, I know binomial theorem.

Comment: (This is what @user121270 meant by the last line:) $$=\frac{(n^5+5n^4)^2-(n^2+2n)^5}{(\sqrt[10]{(n^5+5n^4)^2})^9\sqrt[10]{(n^2+2n)^‌​5}+\cdots} $$

Comment: Thank you @anorton I will delete my post

Comment: You mean to multiply by (a+b) to get rid of roots in the numerator?

Comment: Yes @Timof, you are right.

Comment: And what to do with this fraction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the general fact 
$$n(n+a-\sqrt[k]{n^k +akn^{k-1}})\rightarrow \frac{k+1}{2}a^2$$ as $n\to \infty$

to get a limit of

$$\frac{2+1}{2}-\frac{5+1}{2}=-\frac{3}{2}$$

For proof of the above fact.
If we let $A=\sqrt[k]{n^k +akn^{k-1}}$
then $$n((n+a)-A)=n\frac{(n+a)^k-A^k}{(n+a)^{k-1}+\cdots +A^{k-1}}
=\frac{\binom{k}{2}a^2n^{k-1}+\cdots }{(n+a)^{k-1}+\cdots +A^{k-1}}\rightarrow \frac{k+1}{2}a^2$$

Comment: @Timof thanks, I was to hasty in my conclusions, I have posted an improved answer.

Comment: How did you get this "general fact"?

Comment: @Timof Its an improvement of my earlier general fact. Or do you mean how is it proved ?

Comment: The latter, but it looks like the same binomial expansion, right?

Comment: @Timof I added my proof.

Answer (score 2):

A very broad hint: $\sqrt[k]{n^k+an^{k-1}}$ $= n\sqrt[k]{1+\frac an}$ $\approx ??$ — you should be able to fill in the ?? here using the binomial theorem (note that you'll need more than just the first term!); do this for both radicals in your limit and simplify.

Comment: $n \cdot (1 + \frac{a}{kn} + \frac{a^2 }{2n^2 k(k-1)}) => n^2 \cdot (\frac{5}{5n} + \frac{25 }{20 \cdot 2n^2} - \frac{2}{2n} - \frac{4 }{2 \cdot2n^2}) = \frac{5 }{8} - 1 = -3/8 $

Comment: Did I calculate right?

Comment: Btw, how do you determine to use more than 1 term? Is it because of necessity to cancel out $n^2$?

Comment: @Timof Not quite - to find the second term in $(1+x)^{(1/k)}$ you need $\frac12\frac1k\cdot\left(\frac1k-1\right)$, not $\frac12\frac1k\cdot\left(\frac1{k-1}\right)$.  In particular, you should find that the second term is _negative_, not positive; $ 1+\frac xk$ OVERestimates $(1+x)^{(1/k)}$.

Comment: And yes, the need to use more than one term is because you have effectively a factor of $n^2$ in front, so you need to expand to at least $o(n^{-2})$ to be sure of the limit.

Answer (score 1):

Factoring out an $n$ to make the expression $n^2((1+5/n)^{1/5}-(1+2/n)^{1/2})$ allows one to let $n=1/x$ and convert things to

$$\lim_{x\to0}{(1+5x)^{1/5}-(1+2x)^{1/2}\over x^2}$$

A couple of rounds of L'Hopital ought to finish things off.